# Are there $\mathbb{R}$-metrizable spaces which are not $\mathbb{Q}$-metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let's start by generalizing the concept of a metric space. An $S$-metric space is a set $X$ with a function $d : X \times X \to S$ such that

- $d(x,y) = 0 \iff x = y$
- $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$
- $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$

This is just a metric space which need not necessarily map into $\mathbb{R}$.  So my question is:

> Are all $\mathbb{R}$-metrizable spaces also $\mathbb{Q}$-metrizable spaces?

I suspect the answer is "No", but I have yet to come up with a counter example.  I have shown that a few metrizable spaces are $\mathbb{Q}$-metrizable.

For example discrete spaces are $\mathbb{Q}$-metrizable since the usual metric has a range of $\{0,1\}$. Additionally $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-metrizable.  If we take $d$ to be the normal Euclidean metric then we can define $d'$ such that:

$
d'(x,y)=\left\lceil d(x,y)\right\rceil
$

The first two conditions follow trivially from the fact that $d$ is a metric and the third is true by virtue of the fact that $\lceil x+y\rceil \leq \lceil x\rceil + \lceil y\rceil$.

Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is generated by unit balls, this metric generates the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This gives us a whole lot more spaces which are homeomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as well, but I don't see a way to adjust this more generally.

Is there an example of a space which is $\mathbb{R}$-metrizable but not $\mathbb{Q}$-metrizable by the above definition?

Comment: @Kavi why not? If it does though, for sure it's not homeomorphic, since only eventually constant sequences converge

Comment: $d'$ generates the **discrete topology** on $\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: I do believe so, recall that the ceiling $\lceil c\rceil$ is the minimal integer $n$ with $c\le n$. In particular, $\lceil c\rceil =0$ for positive $c$ implies $c=0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How does it not imply that?  If $x=y$ then $d(x,y)=0$ so $d'(x,y)$, and if $d'(x,y)$ since $d(x,y)$ is non-negative $d'(x,y) = 0 \implies d(x,y) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We understand that $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Q$ are both endowed with the standard metric $d(x,y) = \lvert x - y \rvert$. These metrics induce the usual topologies on $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Q$ and make $\mathbb Q$ a subspace of $\mathbb R$. It is well-known that $\mathbb Q$ is a *totally disconnected* space which means that all connected components  are one-point sets.

Note that each $\mathbb Q$-metric on a set $X$ is a metric (= $\mathbb R$-metric) on $X$, thus it induces the usual metric topology on $X$.

Let $(X,d)$ be a $\mathbb Q$-metric space. For each $x_0 \in X$ the function $f_{x_0} : X \to \mathbb Q, f_{x_0}(x) = d(x,x_0)$, is continuous with respect to the metric topology on $X$ and the standard topology on $\mathbb Q$. In fact, for $x_1, x_2 \in X$ the triangle inequality shows $d(x_i,x_0) - d(x_j,x_0) \le d(x_1,x_2)$, i.e. $\lvert f_{x_0}(x_1) - f_{x_0}(x_2) \rvert = \lvert d(x_1,x_0) - d(x_2,x_0) \rvert \le d(x_1,x_2)$.

Now let $C$ be a connected component of $X$ (with respect to the metric topology) and $x_0, x_1 \in C$. We know that $f_{x_0}(C)$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb Q$. The only connected subsets of $\mathbb Q$ are the one-point subspaces, thus $f_{x_0}$ is constant on $C$. Thus $d(x_1,x_0) = f_{x_0}(x_1) = f_{x_0}(x_0) = d(x_0,x_0) = 0$ which implies $x_0 = x_1$. Hence $C$ must be a one-point space. We conclude that $X$ is totally disconnected.

In other words, a necessary condition for a topological space to be metrizable by a $\mathbb Q$-metric is that it is totally disconnected.

Therefore only totally disconnected $\mathbb{R}$-metrizable spaces have a chance to be $\mathbb{Q}$-metrizable. In particular, $\mathbb R$ is not $\mathbb{Q}$-metrizable.

Examples for $\mathbb{Q}$-metrizable spaces are

- All discrete spaces: Take $d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \ne y \\ 0 & x = y  \end{cases}$
- $\mathbb Q$ itself

Answer (score 5):

${\bf R}$ is not ${\bf Q}$-metrizable. In fact no connected set $X$ is $\bf Q$-metrizable. Let
$$\phi(x,y) = d(x,y) \in {\bf Q}$$
This is a continuous function. If $X$ is connected, so is $X\times X$ and so is its image $\phi(X\times X)$. The only connected subset of $\bf Q$ containing $0$ is $\{0\}$ hence $\phi$ is zero everywhere.

Here I am assuming that the topology given by the $\bf Q$-distance is the euclidean one. If we do not make this assumption, then we can put a $\bf Q$-distance on all spaces that are in bijection with $\bf R$ because $\bf R$ itself is in bijection with $\{0,1\}^{\bf N}$ and $\{0,1\}^{\bf N}$ possesses the $\bf Q$-distance
$$
d(\{x_n\}_{n \in {\bf N}},\{y_n\}_{n \in {\bf N}}) = 2^{-\min\{n \in {\bf N} \mid x_n \neq y_n\}}.
$$

Comment: You are assuming conncetedness in the metric $d$. Connectedness in the usual metric is of no consequence.$d$ may not be continuous w.r.t. the usual metric.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Connectedness is a topological concept and does not depend on the metric generating the topology of the space.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Connectedness is not a metric property, it is a topological property. When OP say "a space", they presumably mean "a topological space", hence, fixing a topology in advance. This is how metrization is normally understood.

Comment: @Kavi I am assuming that the $\bf Q$-distance gives the standard euclidean topology. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: On every set, the discrete metric is even a $\{0,1\}$-metric and hence also a $\mathbb Q$-metric.

Comment: @Jochen Indeed! Note that the one I build is not discrete. It has in fact no isolated points.